# Can not deploy custom MFP docker image on IBM Bluemix

Tags: docker, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

I've been following the [documentation](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/bluemix/run-foundation-on-bluemix/) to set up a custom MFP Docker Image on Bluemix, but I am not getting the image uploaded. I filled out all script properties and ran them in order as mentioned on our getting started doc. If I execute the prepare server script, I get the following output:

```
    $ ./prepareserver.sh args/prepareserver.properties 
    Arguments : 
    ----------- 

    SERVER_IMAGE_TAG :  registry.ng.bluemix.net/sutter/mfpserver71
    PROJECT_LOC :  /Users/XX/Documents/Mobile/Worklight/Demo/temp/addApp/MobileFirstStarter

    /Users/XX/Documents/Mobile/Worklight/Demo/temp/addApp/MobileFirstStarter is a valid project path. Copying project artifacts. 
    copying applications  /Users/XX/Documents/Mobile/Worklight/Demo/temp/addApp/MobileFirstStarter/bin//MyHybrid-common.wlapp
```

Then the script stops. I’ve browsed through the script and I assume that it gets stuck in line 136 when it tries to add a copy statement to my dockerfile (as the dockerfile is not changed on disk). Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Was the project properly built? Do you have in the bin folder all expected files? .wlapp, .adapter and .war files?

Comment: Yes, the project was properly build and runs perfectly on a local server. All files (.war, .adapter, .wlapp) are copied to mfpf-server/usr/projects/MobileFirstStarter/bin folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to the fact that the grep function was crashing. I've solved the issue with the IBM support by performing the grep in another shell.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can supply the PROJECT_LOC

**Approach-1.** Provide the absolute path of the project war to the "PROJECT_LOC" within the prepareserver.properties file.

e.g.
PROJECT_LOC=/Users/XX/Documents/Mobile/Worklight/Demo/temp/addApp/

Location of WAR files

**Approach-2:** (In this case PROJECT_LOC with in the properties file can be kept empty)

Place the project war within the folder named as the Project within "ibm-mfpf-container-7.1.0.0-eval/mfpf-server/usr/*PROJECTNAME*/bin"

E.g. 
Following MUST be the structure.

```
ibm-mfpf-container-7.1.0.0-eval/mfpf-server/usr/projects
            |
            +------TestProject/
                        |
                        +---- bin/TestProject.war
                        |
                        +---- server/
                        |       |
                        +       +--------conf 
                        |               |
                        |               +------- authenticationConfig.xml
                        |               +------- SMSConfig.xml
                        +----- lib  (you can keep this lib is empty)
```

Note: make sure in the approach-2, the directory name which encloses the Project war should be same as the Project.war name. For instance in your case it should be like

> ibm-mfpf-container-7.1.0.0-eval/mfpf-server/usr/projects/MobileFirstStarter/MobileFirstStater.war

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Unfortunately, I do not get past the buildprojects function. I was not able to execute approach 1, as the script always complained: MobileFirstStarter.war is not a valid project path or it does not contain a runtime .war file in the [...] /bin/MobileFirstStarter.war/bin/ directory. find: [...] /MobileFirstStarter.war/: Not a directory. So, the script says that it expects a directory. If I supply the directory in the project path, it will copy .war, .wlapp, and .adapter files. Same, if I copy everything manually. The dockerfile remains unchanged in both approaches.